# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on array

Tags: php, fetch

**Código donde me aparece el error**
me aparece error en el fetch_object, no se manejar bien esa función busque opciones y me sigue arrojando error, ¿será por versiones de php?

```
<?php 
    require_once "../modelos/Categoria.php";
    
    $categoria=new Categoria();
    
    $idcategoria=isset($_POST["idcategoria"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["idcategoria"]):"";
    $nombre=isset($_POST["nombre"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["nombre"]):"";
    $descripcion=isset($_POST["descripcion"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["descripcion"]):"";
    
    switch ($_GET["op"]){
        case 'guardaryeditar':
            if (empty($idcategoria)){
                $rspta=$categoria->insertar($nombre,$descripcion);
                echo $rspta ? "Categoría registrada" : "Categoría no se pudo registrar";
            }
            else {
                $rspta=$categoria->editar($idcategoria,$nombre,$descripcion);
                echo $rspta ? "Categoría actualizada" : "Categoría no se pudo actualizar";
            }
    break;

    case 'desactivar':
        $rspta=$categoria->desactivar($idcategoria);
        echo $rspta ? "Categoría Desactivada" : "Categoría no se puede desactivar";
        break;
    break;

    case 'activar':
        $rspta=$categoria->activar($idcategoria);
        echo $rspta ? "Categoría activada" : "Categoría no se puede activar";
        break;
    break;

    case 'mostrar':
        $rspta=$categoria->mostrar($idcategoria);
        //Codificar el resultado utilizando json
        echo json_encode($rspta);
        break;
    break;

    case 'listar':
        $rspta=$categoria->listar();
        //Vamos a declarar un array

    $data= Array();
```

> **ERROR EN FETCH_OBJECT:Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on array** el código esta unido, solo quiero resaltar el error.

```
    while ( $reg=$rspta->fetch_object()){
        $data[]=array(
            "0"=>($reg->condicion),
            "1"=>$reg->nombre,
            "2"=>$reg->descripcion,
            "3"=>($reg->condicion)
            );
    }
    $results = array(
        "sEcho"=>1, //Información para el datatables
        "iTotalRecords"=>count($data), //enviamos el total registros al datatable
        "iTotalDisplayRecords"=>count($data), //enviamos el total registros a visualizar
        "aaData"=>$data);
    echo json_encode($results);

break;
}

?>
```

En otra carpeta tengo el query: solo hago un llamado sencillo(La consulta la ejecute y funciona bien.

```
public function listar()
{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM categoria ORDER BY idcategoria DESC";
    return ejecutarConsulta($sql);      
}
```

Conexión a mi Base de datos: Solo hago la conexión a mi BD y la conexión es satisfactoria, en la primera función ocupo el *fetch_all*, no se si sea correcto el uso o si tenga que ver con un error.

```
 <?php 
require_once "global.php";

//Establecer conexion a la base de datos con los parametros del archivo GLOBAL.PHP

$conexion = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
mysqli_query($conexion,'SET NAMES"'.DB_ENCODE.'"');//USO DE CARACTERES ESPECIALEs utf8 
//Mostrar si hay posible error en la CONEXIÓN A LA BASE DE DATOS
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    printf("Fallo en la conexión a la base de datos: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
if(!function_exists('ejecutarConsulta')){
```

En esta función ocupo el *fetch_all*:

```
function ejecutarConsulta($sql){

        global $conexion;
        $query =$conexion-> query($sql);
    $row = $query-> fetch_all();
    return $row;
}
function ejecutarConsultaSimpleFila($sql){

    global $conexion;
    $query =$conexion-> query($sql);
    return $query;
}
function ejecutarConsulta_retornarID($sql){

    global $conexion;
    $query =$conexion-> query($sql);
    return $conexion->insert_id;
}
function limpiarCadena($str){

    global $conexion;
    $str = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,trim($str));
    return htmlspecialchars($str);
}
}

?>
```

Comment: hola, una simple pregunta, cuando ejecutar el `query` que datos te retorna?? un `objeto de PDO` o un `Array`; puede verificarlo con `var_dump()`

Comment: me imprime lo siguiente: array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(11) "Categoria 1" [2]=> string(6) "Desc 1" [3]=> string(1) "1" } }

Comment: no puedes hacerle `fetch` a un `array`, `fetch` es para objetos de `PDO`: https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: Pon **el contexto** en el que obtienes `$reg`. El mensaje te dice claramente que `$reg` ya es un array, entonces es cuestión de recorrer ese array para leer sus datos. Los método `fetch` son para leer el recurso que te devuelve una consulta SQL. Eso ya ocurrió en el método que llamas para obtener a `$reg`. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta y poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Tenia este código:  while ( $reg=$rspta->fetch_object()){
        $data[]=array(
            "0"=>($reg->condicion),
            "1"=>$reg->nombre,
            "2"=>$reg->descripcion,
            "3"=>($reg->condicion)
            );                                                                              
              Sustituí así:                             
  $reg= $rspta;
   while ( $rspta){
    $data[]=array(
     "0"=>($reg->condicion),
     "1"=>$reg->nombre,
     "2"=>$reg->descripcion,
     "3"=>($reg->condicion)
     );